# Dynamically adding .kv childwidgets in python

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to add labels (in this case LightL and DarkL) dynamically within another (grid)layout widget within python.

I tried to use IDs, but I'm unsure how to implement it using add_widget.
The childlabels have a backgroundcolor (rectangle) and I would like all the newly created to be in the same format.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
import kivy

kv = Builder.load_string("""
<BackgroundColor@Widget>
    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: root.background_color
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

<LightL@Label+BackgroundColor>
    background_color: 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 1
    size_hint_x: 0.0725
<DarkL@Label+BackgroundColor>
    background_color: 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1

<IndexScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
       id: DynBox

       GridLayout:
           cols: 4
           LightL:
               id: LightLid
               text: ""
           DarkL:
               id: DarkLid
               text: ""
       BoxLayout:
           orientation: 'vertical'
           Label:
               text:'topright'
           Label:
               text:'bottomright'
""")

class IndexScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    xn = NumericProperty()

    def build(self):
        self.root = kv
        self.AddLabel()
        return self.root

    def AddLabel(self, *arg):
        for xn in range(0, 8):
            App.DarkLid.add_widget(Builder.load_string('''
Label:
    text:
        '#D: {}'.format(self.xn)
'''))
            App.LightLid.add_widget(Builder.load_string('''
Label:
    text:
        '#L: {}'.format(self.xn)
'''))
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run
```

Comment: Structure of my program was all messed up and the layers were weird.
Rewriting it and adjusting things as John mentioned worked out.
Including the colors on the labels!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with your `kv` definition of `LightL` and `DarkL`. It works if you simplify those definitions like this:

```
<LightL@Label>:
    background_color:  0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 1
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: root.background_color
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
<DarkL@Label>:
    background_color:  0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: root.background_color
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
```

Then, modifying your `AddLabel()` method:

```
    def AddLabel(self, *arg):
        for xn in range(0, 8):
            self.root.ids.DynBox.add_widget(Builder.load_string('''
Label:
    text:
        ''' + '\'{}\''.format(xn)
))
            self.root.ids.DynBox.add_widget(Builder.load_string('''
Label:
    text:
        ''' + '\'{}\''.format(xn)
))
```

The `format(xn)` cannot be inside the triple quotes, otherwise it is not executed. It appeared that you were trying to dynamically add the new `Labels` to the existing `DarkL` or `LightL`, but they are not widget containers, so I changed that to the `BoxLayout` just to demonstrate that it works.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! While trying to simplify my code, I noticed I made some messy mistakes. I'm fairly new with kivy and python, so excuses for the simple mistakes.

I adjusted the following:
`
self.root = Builder.loadString(....)
`
`def build(self):
        self.AddLabel()
        return self.root
`

If the changes are correct, I'm getting an AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'.
I'm not sure what this means exactly.

Comment: Also what I was wondering was that I tried to create a dark label and light label for every for loop. Right now it looks like it will just create two labels (?), is there a way to assign the dark/light format to the newly created label? Lastly I was wondering what you changed into BoxLayout (sorry for the spam....)

Comment: If you call `AddLabel()` inside the `build()` method, the `ids` will not yet be available. That causes the `AttributeError`. You must wait to call `AddLabel()` until the `App` is actually completeyl setup and running.  Use somethink like a `Button` or `Clock.schedule_once()` to trigger `AddLabel()`.

Comment: If you want the loop to create dark `Labels` and light `Labels`, then just replace `Label` with `DarkL` or `LightL` inside the loop if `AddLabel()`.

Comment: I'm slowly getting it, thanks for the help!

So I added a button (changed the `Label` in `BoxLayout` that has the text `bottomright` into a button and added `on_release: app.AddLabel()`

However I get the following error:
`in AddLabel
     self.root.ids.DynBox.add_widget(Builder.load_string('''
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 863, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute __getattr__`

I think I'm forgetting something, but not sure what.

Comment: Are you still calling the `AddLabel()` method from the `build()` method?

Comment: No, at the end of the kv  builder (`BoxLayout`), I replaced `Label` with `Button:` and added a line `on_release: app.AddLabel()`